# PowerBI Dax: Adding a filter to the data before I sum by category

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of data and I've written a basic DAX measure that just sums a field called Costs by another called Standard Name:

Global Sum by Borrower = CALCULATE(SUM('4Q21 Portfolio Data'[Cost (000)]),ALLEXCEPT('4Q21 Portfolio Data','4Q21 Portfolio Data'[Standard Name]))

There's a third column called Maturity Date and I want to exclude/filter out any values that have a Maturity Date that's blank from that sum

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trying this:

```
Global Sum by Borrower =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( '4Q21 Portfolio Data'[Cost (000)] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( '4Q21 Portfolio Data', '4Q21 Portfolio Data'[Standard Name] ),
    NOT ISBLANK ( '4Q21 Portfolio Data'[Maturity Date] )
)
```

Comment: You're welcome! I am pleased that your problem is solved.